# Ubuntu 13.04 Log-In Loop

Tags: unity, 13.04, gnome, login

I've seen other posts with this problem (so I know it's not unheard of), but I've gone through most of the suggested fixes without much luck. I made sure .Xauthority is owned by me and not root (-rw-------  1 jgodwin jgodwin  150 Sep 14 15:24 .Xauthority) and I have not made any edits to my .profile. Here is what my .xsessions-errors looks like:

```
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/jgodwin/.compiz/session/10eca48925146e8b2e137917707984620100000024460031"
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type GdkColor

  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: Warning: g_value_unset: assertion `G_IS_VALUE (value)' failed
  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/fluxgui/fluxgui.py:162: GtkWarning: Cannot transform xsetting Net/IconThemeName of type gchararray to type gint

  'gtk-icon-theme-name')
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade

(nautilus:2593): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(nautilus:2593): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Warn: Attempted to restack relative to 0x1800009 which is not a child of the root window or a window compiz owns
** Message: moving back from GtkStatusIcon to indicator

(process:2823): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
** (nm-applet:2576): WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries
** (zeitgeist-datahub:3001): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:231: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): libappindicator-CRITICAL **: app_indicator_set_label: assertion `IS_APP_INDICATOR (self)' failed
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
(gnome-settings-daemon:2524): wacom-plugin-CRITICAL **: gsd_wacom_device_get_device_type: assertion `GSD_IS_WACOM_DEVICE (device)' failed
gnome-session[2446]: CRITICAL: gsm_manager_set_phase: assertion `GSM_IS_MANAGER (manager)' failed
gnome-session[2446]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed
(nm-applet:2576): Gdk-WARNING **: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
gtk-window-decorator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
(update-notifier:3106): Gdk-WARNING **: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
(gnome-screensaver:3000): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-screensaver: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
(telepathy-indicator:2915): Gdk-WARNING **: telepathy-indicator: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
(gnome-fallback-mount-helper:2577): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-fallback-mount-helper: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
(deja-dup-monitor:3136): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
(deja-dup-monitor:3136): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.MTPVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
(deja-dup-monitor:3136): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.AfcVolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
(deja-dup-monitor:3136): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitor-WARNING **: Owner of volume monitor org.gtk.Private.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor disconnected from the bus; removing drives/volumes/mounts
(nautilus:2593): Gdk-WARNING **: nautilus: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.
```

Now there are a lot of things in here that don't sound good, but unfortunately, I'm not really sure what most of them mean. I was using my computer just fine this morning, and rebooted when a Javascript VPN log in applet wasn't working correctly (one that I use routinely without issue from my employer), and after the reboot, I was unable to log in. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced login loop issues and I followed:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
sudo reboot
```